MobX not updating observable component
I have a React app set-up according to a Model-View-Presenter architecture, using MobX Lite to handle states, but I am having issues with my components not re-rendering properly on state changes.
My issue is that my Navbar doesn't update properly after logging in. Using conditional rendering, the Login button should change to Logout, but this doesn't happen.
See my code below.
const Navbar = observer(({model} : {model: LeaderBoardModel}) => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    function handleHomeButtonClick(){

    }

    function handleCreateMatchButtonClick(){

    }

    function handleLoginButtonClick(){
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
            model.setUser(result.user);
            console.log("Logged in as: ", result.user.displayName);
        });
    }

    function handleLogoutButtonClick(){
        signOut(auth);
    }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <NavbarView 
                    model={model} 
                    handleHomeButtonClick={handleHomeButtonClick} 
                    handleCreateMatchButtonClick={handleCreateMatchButtonClick} 
                    handleLoginButtonClick={handleLoginButtonClick} 
                    handleLogoutButtonClick={handleLogoutButtonClick}>
                </NavbarView>
            </div>
        )
})

export function NavbarView({model, handleHomeButtonClick, handleCreateMatchButtonClick, handleLoginButtonClick, handleLogoutButtonClick}) {
    function onHomeButtonClickACB(e){
        handleHomeButtonClick();
    }

    function onCreateMatchButtonClick(e){
        handleCreateMatchButtonClick();
    }

    function onLoginButtonClick(e){
        handleLoginButtonClick();
    }

    function onLogoutButtonClick(e){
        handleLogoutButtonClick();
    }
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <AppBar className="MuiAppBar" position="sticky">
                <Toolbar className="MuiToolbar">
                    <div className="home-button">
                        <IconButton onClick={(e) => onHomeButtonClickACB(e)}>
                            <Home/>
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                    <div className="create-match-button">
                        <Button variant="contained" disabled={!model.user} onClick={(e) => onCreateMatchButtonClick(e)}>
                            {model.user && "Create Match" || !model.user && "Sign in to create match"}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    {!model.user && <div className="login-button">
                        <Button variant="contained" onClick={(e) => onLoginButtonClick(e)}>
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </div>}

                    {model.user && <div className="logout-button">
                        <Button variant="contained" onClick={(e) => onLogoutButtonClick(e)}>
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                    </div>}
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}

 @action setUser(user: User | null) {
        this.user = user;
        this.matchUnderCreation.userID = user?.uid;
    }

I have used the browser debugger to identify the issue. I can see that, after running the setUser function, the model has a valid user, yet this does not trigger the Navbar to re-render.
